# Extracting device name of a string

Tags: java, adb

I'm trying to extract device name for android using *"adb devices"* command ..
successfully by using this method I got that:

```
public void newExec() throws IOException, InterruptedException, BadLocationException{
    String adbPath = "/Volumes/development/android-sdk-macosx/tools/adb";
    String cmd = adbPath+" "+"devices";

    Process p;
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    p.waitFor();

    String line;

    BufferedReader err = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
    while ((line = err.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    err.close();

    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    while ((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
        //printing in the console 
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    input.close();
}
```

The output is:

> List of devices attached
>   192.168.56.101:5555   device

I tried to get only the device name out of this output which is:

> 192.168.56.101:5555

I used split in many ways such as:

```
String devices = "List of devices attached";
System.out.println(line.split(devices);
```

but this is not working at all!

I don't want a static way, but dynamic one. I mean if the device name changed or there are more than one listed devices I want a way to just give the device name only.
is there a way of that?

Sorry if the question is not that clear, I'm little new to Java :)

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Android API, so I don't know if there's a better suited method.  But, if I only had the above to work with, I'd use a regex to capture the device name.

Comment: `String#split` - "Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode character array." `line.split(devices)` would split your string at every instance of `List of devices attached`. Since your string is in the format `#.#.#.#:# device` why not split it at the space? The regex for that would be `"\\s*"`

Comment: SO is a great resource for people who know what they are looking for. But at your level it took you nearly 2 months and close to 10 attempts of asking the same question before you could properly phrase it and finally receive an answer. Why won't you find a local mentor? It would help you to progress much faster than your current pace

Comment: @AlexP. if you mean  that form me I understand you and I know that :) I always say it to my self, the problem is that I don't have the basics, I'm jumping to semi-advanced things! I've addressing the problem since I started my MSc project, and I just want to finish it and then I will try to start from the scratch and understand every thing properly! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below code :

The next line of output of `adb devices` is separated  by tabs, so we have to use "\t" as argument.

```
List<String> deviceList = new ArrayList<String>();

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.endsWith("device")) {
        deviceList.add(line.split("\\t")[0]);
    }

}

for (String device : deviceList) {
    System.out.println(device);
}
```

Comment: @JonnyHenly when you run `adb devices` command then output is separated by tabs not spaces .

Comment: Ahhh I see, my fault. SO turns multiple spaces into one space when not in a `<pre>` block.

Comment: This one is work but when the output is duplicated and printed two times: 192.168.56.101:5555
192.168.56.101:5555

Comment: for duplicate output thing, you can use `set` , then output will contain only unique data.

Comment: even when I use set the duplication is there !

Comment: @SachinGupta
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
if(line.endsWith("device")){
    set.add(line.split("\t")[0]);
   }
   
   for (String dev : set){
   System.out.println(dev);
  }

Comment: When I put them in the textArea there is no duplication textArea.setText(dev);
that's what i need exactly,, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code (Note: it only work if the string output is same every time)

```
String devices = "List of devices attached 192.168.56.101:5555 device";
String[] str = devices.split(' '); //spliting the string from space
System.out.println(str[4]);
```

Output:

> 192.168.56.101:5555

Hope this will help you.

Comment: since i am splitting the string from the `<space>` which in return will give be the splitted strings in array and if you count the array then the 4th index will content the `192.168.56.101:5555`

Comment: oh ! m so sorry its a typing mistake i will rectify it

Comment: Haha no biggie, I thought the error was on my part and I had missed something.

Comment: ha ha ha. But thanks for telling which help me to point out my mistake. Thanks once again ... Hope now its working as gives you desired output..

Answer (score 0):

I am not much familiar with Android programming but to me this sounds like a simple string parsing issue than being specific to android. Anyways, my 2 cents here. You could try parsing the lines only if it ends with

```
        String line;
        List<String> devices = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while((line=input.readLine())!=null){
            //printing in the console 
            System.out.println(line);
            if (!line.endsWith("device")) {
                //skip if it does not ends with suffix 'device'
                continue;
            }
            else {
                //parse it now
                String[] str = line.split(" ");
                devices.add(str[0]);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears that you are using the `String` `split()` method wrong.

```
  String devices = "List of devices attached";

    System.out.println(line.split(devices);
```

An example of use:

```
        String[] ss = "This is a test".split("a");
    
    for (String s: ss )
        System.out.println(s);
```

OUTPUT

> This is
>
> test

The parameter of `split(String regex)` must be a Regular Expression (regex).
Also, you could use a `StringTokenizer` class, or a `Scanner` class. These classes have more options to tokenize.